# Wamp server on windows 10 Icon Red and I can't left or right click on it either

Tags: mysql, apache, icons, wamp

OK: Not only is my WAMP Icon Red but I can't get anything to appear if I right or left click on it. Hovering over the icon I get "None of 2 services running - server off line".

I have

- Installed VC C++ Redist from 2008 - 2015.
- Uninstalled Skype.
- Disabled World Wide Web Publishing Services.
- Made sure my Host file had `"127.0.0.1 localhost"` and `"::1 localhost"` enabled.
- Installed 32bit version of WAMP.

I would given changing the listening Ports a crack but not being able to click on the WAMP icon I wasn't confident enough to change the files in the folders (Eg. Found multiple copies of `httpd.conf`). Would have thought steps 2 and 3 would have made this unnecessary anyway.

If in Services, I manually start `wampapache` and `wampmysql` I can access `localhost/phpmyadmin` and `localhost/domainfolder`, set up databases, install wordpress, etc. Clearly something is going wrong and I'm sure it's destined to give me furthur grief. Any Ideas? I have included my error logs and a screen shot below with my system info.

```
"Apache_error_log" 

[Thu May 05 13:17:27.453022 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 8056:tid 120] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu May 05 13:17:27.484243 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8056:tid 120] AH00455: Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) PHP/5.6.15 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu May 05 13:17:27.484243 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8056:tid 120] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Oct 11 2015 16:06:02
[Thu May 05 13:17:27.484243 2016] [core:notice] [pid 8056:tid 120] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.17\bin\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.17'
[Thu May 05 13:17:27.484243 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8056:tid 120] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 6692
[Thu May 05 13:17:27.874894 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 6692:tid 428] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu May 05 13:17:27.890536 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6692:tid 428] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Thu May 05 14:14:30.816395 2016] [authz_core:error] [pid 6692:tid 1100] [client 192.168.0.166:2569] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp/www/
[Thu May 05 14:30:49.331784 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8056:tid 120] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Thu May 05 14:30:51.363140 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6692:tid 428] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Thu May 05 14:30:53.144329 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8056:tid 120] AH00430: Parent: Child process 6692 exited successfully.
[Thu May 05 15:01:43.930134 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 7168:tid 592] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu May 05 15:01:44.273944 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7168:tid 592] AH00455: Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) PHP/5.6.15 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu May 05 15:01:44.273944 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7168:tid 592] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Oct 11 2015 16:06:02
[Thu May 05 15:01:44.273944 2016] [core:notice] [pid 7168:tid 592] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.17\bin\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.17'
[Thu May 05 15:01:44.273944 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7168:tid 592] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 628
[Thu May 05 15:01:44.711410 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 628:tid 492] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu May 05 15:01:44.805095 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 628:tid 492] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.

"Last 10 lines of PHP_error_log" 

[05-May-2016 05:14:53 UTC] PHP Warning: fopen(C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.17/conf/httpd.conf): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\wamp\scripts\wampserver.lib.php on line 307
[05-May-2016 05:14:53 UTC] PHP Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\scripts\wampserver.lib.php on line 308
[05-May-2016 05:14:53 UTC] PHP Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\scripts\wampserver.lib.php on line 309
[05-May-2016 05:14:54 UTC] PHP Warning: fopen(../wampmanager.ini): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\wamp\scripts\refresh.php on line 1205 [05-May-2016 05:14:54 UTC] PHP Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\scripts\refresh.php on line 1206
[05-May-2016 05:14:54 UTC] PHP Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\scripts\refresh.php on line 1207 [05-May-2016 05:14:54 UTC] PHP Warning: unlink(C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.17/bin/icudt54.dll): Permission denied in C:\wamp\scripts\wampserver.lib.php on line 78
[05-May-2016 05:14:54 UTC] PHP Warning: symlink(): Cannot create symlink, error code(1314) in C:\wamp\scripts\wampserver.lib.php on line 81 [05-May-2016 05:14:54 UTC] PHP Warning: unlink(C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.17/bin/icuin54.dll): Permission denied in C:\wamp\scripts\wampserver.lib.php on line 78
[05-May-2016 05:14:54 UTC] PHP Warning: symlink(): Cannot create symlink, error code(1314) in C:\wamp\scripts\wampserver.lib.php on line 81 [05-May-2016 05:14:54 UTC] PHP Warning: unlink(C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.17/bin/icuio54.dll): Permission denied in C:\wamp\scripts\wampserver.lib.php on line 78
[05-May-2016 05:14:54 UTC] PHP Warning: symlink(): Cannot create symlink, error code(1314) in C:\wamp\scripts\wampserver.lib.php on line 81 [05-May-2016 05:14:54 UTC] PHP Warning: unlink(C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.17/bin/icule54.dll): Permission denied in C:\wamp\scripts\wampserver.lib.php on line 78
```

[System Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AH1t0.png)

Answer (score 2):

Did you install WAMPServer 3 as an Administrator, using the "Run as Administrator" as instructed in the install instructions.

## The installer must be run "as an administrator"

If you did not, uninstall WAMPServer and then reinstall it doing this:

Right click on the installer `.exe` and select "Run as Administrator"

Comment: Hi, I did. I have installed and reinstalled quite a few times (not just wamp but VC C++) trying to vary options / procedure each time to see if it would make a difference. I will try installing wamp as Admin again but I feel confident that this issue lies elsewhere.

Comment: @KarlHonda It also looks like you are running it without runing as Administrator

Answer (score 0):

did you have any missing DLLs while installing wampserver?
I had the same problem and the solution was

1. close the wampserver tray (from task manager)
2. go [Here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679) and download the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio and install it.
3. now open Wamp as administrator

**the problem should be gone by now (*at least that was the solution for me*)**